# Creating A pointcut using args designator with no types results in BeanCurrentlyInCreationException

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop, pointcut

Using `Spring AOP`, when attempting to create a `Pointcut` using the designator `args` while not providing any types results in a series of exceptions starting with `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException`

**The Example**

```
object _001_Spring_AOP_Pointcut_Args_NoArgs {

    open class BeanA {
        open fun m() {
            println("BeanA#m()")
        }
    }

    @Aspect
    class AspectA {
        @Pointcut("args()")
        private fun pc_noArgs() = Unit

        @After("sero4.spring.z_added._001_Spring_AOP_Pointcut_Args_NoArgs.AspectA.pc_noArgs()")
        private fun ac_noArgs() = println("ac_noArgs")
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
    open class Config {
        @Bean
        open fun beanA(): BeanA = BeanA()

        @Bean
        open fun aspectA(): AspectA = AspectA()
    }

    fun runJava() {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config::class.java)
    }

}
```

**The Run Method**

```
    @Test
    fun test_run() {
        _001_Spring_AOP_Pointcut_Args_NoArgs.runJava()
    }
```

**The Exception Summary**

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'beanA' defined in sero4.spring.z_added._001_Spring_AOP_Pointcut_Args_NoArgs$Config: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [sero4.spring.z_added._001_Spring_AOP_Pointcut_Args_NoArgs$BeanA]: Factory method 'beanA' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aspectA' defined in sero4.spring.z_added._001_Spring_AOP_Pointcut_Args_NoArgs$Config: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [sero4.spring.z_added._001_Spring_AOP_Pointcut_Args_NoArgs$AspectA]: Factory method 'aspectA' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'aspectA': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### `args()` vs. `execution(* *())`

This is an unusual way of intercepting all methods without parameters. I would rather make it more explicit and use `execution(* *())` instead. If you ever migrate from Spring AOP to AspectJ, you will notice that `args()` matches all kinds of pointcuts there, e.g. `call`, `initialization`, `preinitialization`, `staticinitialization`, `get` and constructor calls/executions without parameters.

#### Pointcut scoping

Here in Spring AOP your problem might be another one, though: Your pointcut is too broad. It matches many joinpoints in Spring beans, also in Spring or third-party classes themselves. So you want to limit the scope of your pointcut, e.g. something like

```java
execution(* *()) && within(my.own.package.**)
```

#### When to (not) use fully qualified class names in pointcuts

BTW, if your pointcut is defined in the very same class as the advice using it, it should not be necessary to use a fully qualified class name, i.e. instead of

```java
@After("sero4.spring.z_added._001_Spring_AOP_Pointcut_Args_NoArgs.AspectA.pc_noArgs()")
```

you could use

```java
@After("pc_noArgs()")
```

#### Inline pointcuts

If you have no plans to re-use the same pointcut in other advices, just get rid of `@Pointcut` and define an inline pointcut such as

```java
@After("execution(* *()) && within(my.own.package.**)")
```

#### Advices should be `public`

While it is OK to define the `@Pointcut` method as private if you do not refer to it from other classes, the `@After` advice should be public. It might work in Spring AOP, but is against conventions. Again, if you ever migrate to AspectJ, you will even get a compile error because an AspectJ advice must be public.

Comment: Excellent points.Couple of my observations from debugging the code. If the PCD has the scope within the package of the aspect class , it fails with the exception mentioned. Here the question shared , both target bean and aspect are in the same package it appears .So even if the scope is limited , it might not work as expected. However if the target bean is moved to another package and the scope to advice is only that package , it succeeds . eg : `@Pointcut("args() && within(rg.spring.boot.bean.*)")`

Comment: Well, even if they are in the same package you could do `within(my.own.package.**) && !within(**.AspectA)` or so. That is just fine tuning. Actually the more interesting question is why Spring AOP would stumble across an aspect because according to the documentation Spring AOP aspects are exempt from aspect weaving, unlike in AspectJ where is is perfectly permissable for one aspect to intercept another one. IMO this is would be a Spring bug then.

Answer (score 1):

The code shared fails with the following exception -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException
```

, when the `pointcut` expression has a scope within the package the aspect class resides.

**Example:**

Fully qualified names for the beans :

```
rg.spring.boot.AspectA

rg.spring.boot.bean.BeanA
```

And a pointcut expression like the following would fail:

```
@Pointcut("args() && within(rg.spring.boot..*)")
```

whereas, the following pointcut expression succeeds :

```
@Pointcut("args() && within(rg.spring.boot.bean..*)")
```

The exception, as *per* me, is because the `pointcut` targets framework methods of the aspect during initialization. To resolve the exception, you may move the bean to a specific package and fine tune the scope of the `pointcut` expression for that package.